# How can I show a loading image during AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading another page in to a `div` with the help of this jQuery code:

```
$('#maildiv').load('reports/mail_report.php');
```

The load is taking some time. Meanwhile I want to show a loading image. When the file message is loaded the loading image should be hidden.

How can I do this?

I tried with:

```
function mail() {
    $("#mailimg").show();
    $('#maildiv').load('reports/mail_report.php') {
        $("#mailimg").fadeOut("10000");
        $('#maildiv').fadeOut("10000");
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class='button green' value="Mail Report" name="" id=""  Onclick='mail();return false;'/>
<img id="mailimg" style='display:none;' src='img/loading.gif' width='20' height='20'>     
<div id="maildiv" style="color:red;"> </div>
```

Comment: You can use: `.ajaxStart()` and `.ajaxStop()` http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

Comment: Did any of the answers help? If yes please check one so this topic can be considered closed, if not please provide some feedback or an answer of your own.

Answer (score 1):

Use the .load() complete callback to hide the load image.

Another point is the loaded div `maildiv`, why do you want to hide it using `$('#maildiv').fadeOut("10000")`. I think you need to use show it using `$('#maildiv').fadeIn("10000")`

```
function mail() {
    $("#mailimg").show();
    $('#maildiv').load('reports/mail_report.php', function() {
        $("#mailimg").fadeOut("10000");
        $('#maildiv').fadeOut("10000");
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is generic and should solve it for this issue.

```
//Do what you have to before its starts
$('#whereitstobeloads').load('filethatstobeloaded', function() {
  //What you want to do when its loaded
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got the right idea - using a callback function of the `load` - however your syntax is incorrect. Try this:

```
function mail() {
    $('#mailimg').show();
    $('#maildiv').load(
        'reports/mail_report.php'),
        function() {
            $('#mailimg').fadeOut("10000");
            $('#maildiv').fadeOut("10000");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function mail() {
    $("#mailimg").css('display','block');
    $('#maildiv').load('reports/mail_report.php', function(){
    $('#mailimg').animate({
        opacity: 0.0
        }, 1000, 'linear', function(){
            $('#maildiv').animate({
                    opacity: 1.0
                    }, 1000, 'linear');
        });
    });
}
```